# How can I implement a function that is a homomorphism?

Tags: functions, algebraic-manipulation

I want to do the follow: Write a function $f$ such that if I evaluate $f(ax+by)$, it returns $f(a)f(x)+f(b)f(y)$. How can I do that? I tried to look in the help for "homomorphism" but didn't find anything. I suspect there might be another name for this kind of functions in Mathematica.

Comment: Does defining `f[x_ + y_] := f[x] + f[y]` and `f[x_ y_] := f[x]f[y]` help?

Comment: @thorimur I didn't know I could declare functions this way! This is very nice, I was used to `f[x_,y_]:=something` but doing this way you taught me, it opens up a whole new world for me. Thank you very much! If you want it, write an answer and I'll upvote and accept right away!

Comment: @BillyRubina one thing to be aware of is if you need non-commutativity, the multiplication definition will need to be adapted